# Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY confusion

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, java.util.date

I have this piece of code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(pDatum);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(pHHMMTP.substring(0, 2)));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(pHHMMTP.substring(2, 4)));
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

where `pDatum` is `Sun Mar 27 00:00:00 CET 2016`, `pHHMMTP` is `02485` and `pHHMMTP.substring(0, 2)` is `02`.

The output is:

> Sun Mar 27 03:48:00 CEST 2016

I would expect:

> Sun Mar 27 02:48:00 CEST 2016

First I thought it is a `TimeZone` issue but with this code I get the same output:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
cal.setTimeZone(tz);
cal.setTime(pDatum);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(pHHMMTP.substring(0, 2)));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(pHHMMTP.substring(2, 4)));
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Do you see my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CET means *Central European Timezone*. In Europe, there is a notion of [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Basically, in winter, the hour is shifted from 1h. For practical reasons (quality of sleep actually), the time switch is done on the first sunday of spring which is the 27th of march in 2016. Also, for practical reasons, the time switch is done during the night, between 02:00 AM and 03:00 AM, so the clocks counts down like this: `01:58`, `01:59`, `03:00`, `03:01`. This means, `Sun Mar 27 02:48:00 CET 2016` **does not exist**.
As a consequence, if you run your code on `Sun Mar 27`, you will get `03:48` but if you run it on `Mon Mar 28`, you will get `02:48`.

Try with both dates :

```
//Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy z").parse("27/03/2016 CET");
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy z").parse("28/03/2016 CET");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Output :

> Mon Mar 28 02:48:00 CEST 2016

Comment: yes that was the problem. The summer time change ... Thx a lot

Comment: @Tom The reason behind that it that the op used THE wrong day and THE wrong hour because the time switch is done between 02:00 AM and 03:00 AM. As a result, `27 Mar 02:48` does not exist. Clocks count like 02:58 AM, 02:59 AM, 4:00 AM, 4:01 AM...

Comment: @Tom Edited. Tried to make it clear but my english is not very good :) Don't hesitate to edit and rephrase if you are a native speaker.

Comment: Since it is all better now, I cleaned up my obsolete comments :).

Answer (score 1):

It's a TimeZone problem, you're building the calendar in GMT, but printing the date in CEST zone.

Edit:

When the date is printed out with the same timezone, then it's ok:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
  cal.setTimeZone(tz);
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

  System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // <-- System default Zone

  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
  formatter.setTimeZone(tz);

  System.out.print(formatter.format(cal.getTime())); // <-- Same TimeZone
```

Output:

```
Tue Mar 22 03:48:06 CET 2016
Tue Mar 22 02:48:06 GMT 2016
```

Comment: @Tom you're right,  27 march 2016 hours from 2 to 3 doesn't exist because daylight saving. But if he changes to GMT and prints the Date using CET it won't match. I'll fix this

Comment: Now it works, but with one disadvantage: the printed date is in another timezone. The DST is so annoying :D.